# What is the time complexity of this function? (nested for loop)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, time-complexity, big-o

I think it's `O(n * m)` but also think its `O(n)`

Can't really tell which one is correct..

Considering first loop only loops 20 times (fixed amount), and second nested for loop only loops number / 20, and lastly third nested loops 3 times.

So it comes out as `O(n * m / 20 * 3)` which we can call it as `O(n * m * k)`?  is this correct?

or it's `O(n)` because the second loops time complexity will only effect it since it's different depending on what the user inputs as number.

```
function loop(number) {
  let answer = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < number / 20; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        answer++;
      }
    }
  }

  return answer;
}
```

Comment: What are `m` and `n`? The time complexity is `O(number)`

Comment: @jabaa isnt n 20 from the first loop and m the value from number / 20?

Comment: I don't know. You are talking about `m` and `n`, but there aren't such variables in your code. How should I know what you mean with these variables? The only interesting parameter is `number`.

Comment: The `i` loop goes 20 times, the `j` loop goes number/20 times, and the `k` loop goes 3 times, so wouldn't the answer be O(20 * (number / 20) * 3)?

Comment: @jabaa oh, i see where you got confused. Hmm.. i am confused.. so it should just be O(n) since there is only number?

Comment: @kmoser but how would that be described in Big O notation? Any guess?

Comment: @UnJinJang Big O notation needs to define the variables it uses. Even though they're often named `m`,`n`,`k`, their meaning is specific to the algorithm, e.g. if the input is an array then `n` could be its length. In your case, the input is a number (a parameter called `number`), and the run time is linear to its value. So you should write "`O(number)`", or "`O(n)` where `n` is the value of the `number` parameter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop always loops exactly 20 times, the inner loop always loops exactly 3 times. The only one that has any variability is the middle loop, which loops `number` / 20 times. So you will be incrementing `answer` 20 * 3 * (number / 20) times, and since constants are ignored for Big O notation, this works out to `O(number)`.

Comment: There is no `N` in the code. What is `N`? Why would you introduce another variable `N` next to `n`, `m` and `number`?

Comment: Is that a serious question? I hope you're not just nitpicking capitalization. In my answer `number`, `n`, and `N` are the same thing.

Comment: IMO, it's not nitpicky. Obviously the OP doesn't understand big O notation and the meaning of the argument. They are talking about some `m` and `n` and don't know, what it means. The reason is answers like this. A new variable is probably much more confusing. Why not `O(number)`? Where did you write that `N = number`?

Comment: `Where did you write that N = number?` Obviously i never wrote that. Instead, i started by saying it "loops number / 20 times", which i assume you are fine with. Then in the next sentence, I shortened this to "n / 20 times". I assume most people can identity that n and number are the same thing, given the context. Then i said that Big O notation drops constants, and I showed that dropping the constants results in  "O(N)". I assumed most people would realize these n's were the same, but alas! i screwed up my capitalization. Feel free to edit my answer to improve it.